# making parts of string world in Java

Tags: java, string, methods, substring, division

i written this are

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {


   @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

      String girdi;
      int boyut;
      System.out.println("İsim girin:");
      girdi=input.next();  
      System.out.println("Boyut girin");
      boyut=input.nextInt();
      int i=0;
      String cikti=null;

      for (;i < girdi.length(); i++){
          if(boyut==i){

          girdi.substring(boyut);

          cikti=girdi.substring(boyut);
          System.out.println(cikti);
```

im trying to have something like ;

**@console:**

**Enter a name;** 
araba

**Enter a size of division;**
3

but, when i run my code, it cuts left 3 charachter of world then shown.
**i wanna show it;**

---

ara
rab
aba

Answer (score 0):

Trying using `girdi=input.nextLine();`

next only reads the the characters up until the spaces.

On the other hand, nextLine will read the space characters.

Hopefully this is what you were asking for; I'm having difficult understanding your english

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("İsim girin:");
String girdi = input.next();
System.out.println("Boyut girin");
int boyut = input.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i <= girdi.length() - boyut; ++i)
    System.out.print(girdi.substring(i, i + boyut) + " ");
System.out.println();
```